# Jersey Rest services is not working

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, jersey

I have implemented Jersey REST web services for Multipart/form-data, which is working for any tools(SOAP UI) but not working if a request is coming from Application(getting null content while parsing the file).

```
Response solution(Multipart multipart){
    int size=multipart.size();//2
    String file1=multipart.getContentDisposition().get(0).getEntity();//null
}
```

Comment: use FormDataBodyPart jersey class

Comment: How to use FormDataBodyPart when file name is random?

Comment: No problem. you get it following class.